# Exchange data between 2 socket clients using php

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, serversocket

I'm developing a new socket based application for interacting with my clients and I want to achieve that using socket programming.

Let's say my `server socket` is running on `127.0.0.1` on `8888` port. when a client connected to my server & if he trying to send a message to admin where admin is already connected from a different socket client.

But I'm facing a problem exchanging data between admin & client sockets. However the server socket is accepting the data from the admin & client as well. When I'm trying to send client data to admin its not passing over.

**`server.php`**

```
<?
    set_time_limit(0);

    // Set the ip and port we will listen on
    $address = '127.0.0.1';
    $port = 8888;

    // Create a TCP Stream socket
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die('Could not bind to address'); // 0 for  SQL_TCP

    // Bind the socket to an address/port
    socket_bind($sock, 0, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');  //0 for localhost

    // Start listening for connections
    socket_listen($sock);

    $admin = null;
    $clients = array();

    while(true) {
        /* Accept incoming  requests and handle them as child processes */
        $client = socket_accept($sock);

        if(socket_getpeername($client, $address, $port)) {
            echo "Client $address : $port is now connected to us. \n";
        }

        // Read the input  from the client – 2MB bytes
        $input = socket_read($client, 2097152);
        $data = json_decode($input);

        print_r($data);

        if($data->connection === "admin"){
            echo "Admin connection\n";
            $admin = $client;
        }else if($data->connection === "client"){
            echo "Got data from client\n";
            $message = array('client_id' => $data->id, 'message' => $data->message);

            $clients[$data->id] = $client;

            if($admin !== null){
                echo "Sending data to admin\n";
                socket_write($admin, json_encode($message), strlen(json_encode($message)));
            }else{
                echo "Admin not available, sending response to client\n";
                $message = 'Admin not available!';
                socket_write($client, $message, strlen($message));
            }
        }

        print_r($clients);

        // socket_write($client, $response);
        // socket_close($client);
    }

    // Close the master sockets
    socket_close($sock);
?>
```

**`admin.php`**

```
<?
    set_time_limit(0);

    $server = '128.199.XXX.XXX';
    $port = '8888';

    if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    echo "Socket created \n";

    //Connect socket to remote server
    if(!socket_connect($sock, $server, $port)) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    echo "Connection established \n";

    $message = array('connection' => 'admin');

    //Send the message to the server
    if(!socket_send($sock, json_encode($message), strlen(json_encode($message)), 0)) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    echo "Message send successfully \n";

    if(socket_recv($sock, $buf, 10, MSG_WAITALL) === FALSE) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    print_r(json_decode($buf));

?>
```

**`client.php`**

```
<?
    set_time_limit(0);

    $server = '128.199.XXX.XXX';
    $port = '8888';

    if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    echo "Socket created \n";

    //Connect socket to remote server
    if(!socket_connect($sock, $server, $port)) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    echo "Connection established \n";

    $message = array('connection' => 'client', 'id' => time(), 'message' => 'Hi');

    //Send the message to the server
    if(!socket_send($sock, json_encode($message), strlen(json_encode($message)), 0)) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    echo "Message send successfully \n";

    if(socket_recv($sock, $buf, 10, MSG_WAITALL) === FALSE) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    print_r(json_decode($buf));
?>
```

Can anybody done this before? lease help me to achieve it.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: In server.php, the IP address should be `0.0.0.0`.  This is a listening address, not a destination address.  By setting it to `127.0.0.1`, you are telling your server that you only want clients to connect _only if they are on the same machine_.  Setting it to `0.0.0.0` lets anyone connect to it.  Anything other than `0.0.0.0` is only useful if you have multiple network interfaces and you want to restrict traffic to one.

Comment: For further information about the difference between `0.0.0.0` and `127.0.0.1`: https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1

Comment: I've changed `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` nothing specially happens after change it to what you told me @Ghedipunk. My intention is to transfer client data to admin using server.

However both clients & admin are able to connect using the `127.0.0.0`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can able to see when both clients connected as below...

**`When Admin connected to the server`**

Client 128.199.163.24 : 36113 is now connected to us.
stdClass Object
(
    [connection] => admin
)
Admin connection

**`Client connection`**

Client 128.199.163.24 : 36115 is now connected to us.
stdClass Object
(
    [connection] => client
    [id] => 1440522235
    [message] => Hi
)
Got data from client
Sending data to admin
Array
(
    [1440522235] => Resource id #6
)